Showing $\langle v_k, e_k \rangle > 0$ under the Gram-Schmidt procedure
The following is exercise 6.B.9 from Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition, by Sheldon Axler.

Suppose $e_1, \ldots, e_m$ is the result of applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure to a linearly independent list $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ in $V$. Prove that $\langle v_k, e_k \rangle > 0$ for each $k = 1, \ldots, m$.

See here for how Axler's text defines the Gram-Schmidt procedure.
The strategy I was going for was to induct on $k$, but I got stuck. See below for my attempt and questions.
My attempt.
For the base case, let $k = 1$. We have then
$$
\langle v_1, e_1 \rangle = \left \langle v_1, \frac{f_1}{\lVert f_1 \rVert} \right \rangle = \frac{1}{\lVert f_1 \rVert} \langle v_1, f_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\lVert f_1 \rVert} \langle v_1, v_1 \rangle >0
$$
where the last inequality comes from the fact that $\frac{1}{\lVert f_1 \rVert} > 0$, and $\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle > 0$ since $\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle \geq 0$ by definition of inner product and $v_1 \neq 0$ since it's part of a linearly independent list. This closes the base case.
For the inductive hypothesis, we assume the result is true when $k = j$.
We want to show the result is true for $k = j + 1$, i.e., show that $\langle v_{j+1}, e_{j+1}\rangle > 0$. We have that
\begin{align}
\langle v_{j+1}, e_{j+1}\rangle = \left \langle v_{j+1}, \frac{f_{j+1}}{\lVert f_{j+1} \rVert} \right \rangle &= \frac{1} {\lVert f_{j+1} \rVert} \langle v_{j+1}, f_{j+1} \rangle \\
&=\frac{1} {\lVert f_{j+1} \rVert} \left \langle v_{j+1}, v_{j+1} - \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{\langle v_{j+1}, f_i \rangle}{\lVert f_i \rVert ^2} f_i \right \rangle \\ &= \frac{1} {\lVert f_{j+1} \rVert} \left ( \langle v_{j+1}, v_{j+1} \rangle - \left \langle v_{j+1}, \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{\langle v_{j+1}, f_i \rangle}{\lVert f_i \rVert ^2} f_i \right \rangle \right )
\end{align}
To go from here, my idea was to right the last expression as
$$
\frac{1} {\lVert f_{j+1} \rVert} \left ( \langle v_{j+1}, v_{j+1} \rangle - \left \langle f_{j+1} + \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{\langle v_{j+1}, f_i \rangle}{\lVert f_i \rVert ^2} f_i, \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{\langle v_{j+1}, f_i \rangle}{\lVert f_i \rVert ^2} f_i \right \rangle \right )
$$
where I replaced the $v_{j+1}$ in the second inner product term by it's definition given by the Gram-Schmidt procedure.
My hope was that the inner product after the minus sign would equal $0$ by orthogonality, but if I'm looking at it correctly, that can never happen since we'll have the following nonzero inner product
$$
\left \langle \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{\langle v_{j+1}, f_i \rangle}{\lVert f_i \rVert ^2} f_i, \sum_{i = 1}^j \frac{\langle v_{j+1}, f_i \rangle}{\lVert f_i \rVert ^2} f_i \right \rangle
$$
within the whole expression.
I'm not where to go from here, or if I need a different strategy.

You are making your life too complicated. Suppose you have created $e_1,...,e_k$, then the first step is to create $u_{k+1} = v_{k+1}- \sum_k \langle e_j, v_{k+1} \rangle e_j$ and since this is orthogonal to all the $e_1,...,e_k$ by construction, we have $\langle u_{k+1}, u_{k+1} \rangle = \langle u_{k+1}, v_{k+1} \rangle$.

I see. You're saying $u_{k+1}$ is orthogonal to each $e_1, \ldots, e_k$ because $u_{k+1} = \lVert u_{k+1} \rVert e_{k+1}$, and by definition, $\langle \lVert u_{k+1} \rVert e_{k+1}, e_j \rangle = 0$ for $j = 1, \ldots, k$?

@copper.hat Also, it looks like the inductive hypothesis does not get used, right?

That is correct.

You do not need to use induction like that. First, recall that
$$ f_k = v_k- \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \langle v_k, e_j\rangle e_j. $$
You can check here that $f_k$ is orthogonal to all $e_1,\ldots,e_{k-1}$. Since $e_k$ is just a rescaling of $f_k$, for $c_k=\|f_k\|$ we have
$$ v_k =\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\langle v_k, e_j\rangle e_j + c_ke_k. $$
Taking inner product with respect to $e_k$ in the last expression, using the bilinearity of the inner product and the orthogonality of $e_1,\ldots,e_{k-1}$ with $e_k$, we obtain
$$ \langle v_k,e_k\rangle = c_k\langle e_k,e_k\rangle =c_k =\|f_k\|\ge 0.$$
Now, the equality $\|f_k\|=0$ is impossible since we would then have
$$ v_k =\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\langle v_k, e_j\rangle e_j . $$
Since the $e_1,\ldots,e_{k-1}$ are linear combinations of $v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1}$ (say, by induction), this would mean that $v_k$ is in the span of $v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1}$, contradicting the linear independence. Thus,
$$ \langle v_k,e_k\rangle = \|f_k\|>0.$$
